# "Functions" versus "function pointers" -- what's the difference?

Tags: function, function-pointers, d

I'm really confused at [the documentation of `isSomeFunction`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#isSomeFunction), as well as at the following code:

```
static assert(!isFunctionPointer!(typeof(Object.toString)));  // makes sense
static assert(!isDelegate!(typeof(Object.toString)));         // what??
static assert( isSomeFunction!(typeof(Object.toString)));     // what??
```

Could someone please explain the difference between a "function" and a "function pointer" to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Short Answer:

- `is(T == function)`      Whether `T` is a function
- `isFunctionPointer!T`  Whether `T` is a function pointer (and *not* a delegate)
- `isDelegate!T`                Whether `T` is a delegate
- `isSomeFunction!T`        Whether `T` is a function, a function pointer, *or* a delegate

#### Long Answer:

A function is, well, a function.

```
auto func(int val) {...}
```

It's a chunk of code with a name that you can call using that name. You give it arguments, it does whatever it does, and it returns a result. You can call it, but you can't pass it around. You need a function pointer for that.

A function pointer is a pointer to a function. So just like `int` is an `int` and `int*` is a pointer to an `int`, and `int` is *not* a pointer to `int`, a function isn't a function pointer. If you want a function pointer, you need a pointer to a function. The syntax is different from how it is with `int`, but it's the same concept.

A delegate is a function pointer with state. So for instance, in

```
int foo(int value)
{
    int bar()
    {
        return value + 5;
    }

    auto barDel = &bar;

    return barDel();
}

void main()
{
    auto fooFunc = &foo;
}
```

`foo` is a function, `bar` is a nested function which has access to its outer scope, and `barDel` is a delegate, because it's a function pointer with state (the outer state that `bar` has access to). If you pass `barDel` to another function (or return it), you'll get a closure (unless the function it's passed to takes the delegate by `scope`, in which case that function guarantees that the delegate will not escape its scope), because that state needs to be put on the heap so that it continues to exist even if the function call that its state comes from has completed when it's called. `funcFoo`, on the other hand, is a function pointer, because `foo` doesn't have any outer state. If `bar` were `static`, then `barDel` would also be a function pointer rather than a delegate, because `bar` would no longer have access to the function that it's in (though its body would then have to be changed, since it would no longer have access to `value`).

Now, as to your example. `Object.toString` is a member function of `Object`. So, it's a function. It has *no* state associated with it. Functions never do. Its current signature is

```
string toString();
```

But because it's a member function of `Object`, its signature is really something like

```
string toString(Object this);
```

`this` is passed to `toString` as an argument. It's not state associated with `toString`. So, `&Object.toString` is not a delegate. It's just a function pointer. And `Object.toString` isn't a function pointer, so even if `&Object.toString` *were* a delegate, `static assert(isDelegate!(typeof(Object.toString)))` would still fail, because in order to be a delegate, it must be a function pointer, which it's not. It's a function.

Now, unfortunately, `typeof(&Object.toString)` is considered to be `string function()` rather than `string function(Object)`, so using it to call `toString` with an actual `Object` takes a bit of work. It can be done, but I don't remember how at the moment (and it's a bit ugly IIRC). But it wouldn't be a delegate regardless, because there's no state associated with it.

If you want a function that you can pass an `Object` to and have it call a member function, then you could do something like

```
auto obj = getObjectFromSomewhere();
auto func = function(Object obj){return obj.toString();};
auto result = func(obj);
```

If you want to associate an object with a member function and be able to call that member function on that object without having to pass the object around, then you just wrap it in a delegate:

```
auto obj = getObjectFromSomewhere();
auto del = delegate(){return obj.toString();};
auto result = del();
```

This bit of code should sum things up and illustrate things fairly well:

```
int foo(int value)
{
    int bar()
    {
        return value + 5;
    }

    static assert( is(typeof(bar) == function));
    static assert(!isFunctionPointer!(typeof(bar)));
    static assert(!isDelegate!(typeof(bar)));
    static assert( isSomeFunction!(typeof(bar)));

    auto barDel = &bar;
    static assert(!is(typeof(barDel) == function));
    static assert(!isFunctionPointer!(typeof(barDel)));
    static assert( isDelegate!(typeof(barDel)));
    static assert( isSomeFunction!(typeof(barDel)));

    static int boz(int i)
    {
        return i + 2;
    }

    static assert( is(typeof(boz) == function));
    static assert(!isFunctionPointer!(typeof(boz)));
    static assert(!isDelegate!(typeof(boz)));
    static assert(isSomeFunction!(typeof(boz)));

    auto bozFunc = &boz;
    static assert(!is(typeof(bozFunc) == function));
    static assert( isFunctionPointer!(typeof(bozFunc)));
    static assert(!isDelegate!(typeof(bozFunc)));
    static assert( isSomeFunction!(typeof(bozFunc)));

    return boz(bar());
}

static assert( is(typeof(foo) == function));
static assert(!isFunctionPointer!(typeof(foo)));
static assert(!isDelegate!(typeof(foo)));
static assert( isSomeFunction!(typeof(foo)));

void main()
{
    auto fooFunc = &foo;
    static assert(!is(typeof(fooFunc) == function));
    static assert( isFunctionPointer!(typeof(fooFunc)));
    static assert(!isDelegate!(typeof(fooFunc)));
    static assert( isSomeFunction!(typeof(fooFunc)));
}

static assert( is(typeof(Object.toString) == function));
static assert(!isFunctionPointer!(typeof(Object.toString)));
static assert(!isDelegate!(typeof(Object.toString)));
static assert( isSomeFunction!(typeof(Object.toString)));

static assert(!is(typeof(&Object.toString) == function));
static assert( isFunctionPointer!(typeof(&Object.toString)));
static assert(!isDelegate!(typeof(&Object.toString)));
static assert( isSomeFunction!(typeof(&Object.toString)));
```

`isSomeFunction` is `true` for all of them, because they're all either functions, function pointers *without* state, or delegates.

`foo`, `bar`, `boz`, and `Object.toString` are all functions, so they're `true` for `is(T == function)` but not for the others.

`fooFunc`, `bozFunc`, and `&Object.toString` are function pointers *without state*, so they're `true` for `isFunctionPointer!T` but not for the others.

`barDel` is a delegate, so it's `true` for `isDelegate!T` but not for the others.

Hopefully, that clears things up for you.

Comment: Did you intend `and int is not a pointer to int,` to be `and int is not a pointer to int*,` ?

Comment: @jcolebrand No. I meant what I said. `int` is _not_ a pointer to `int`. `int*` is. It's the same with a function. A function is not a function pointer. And if `isFunctionPointer!(Object.toString)` were `true`, that would mean that a function _was_ a function pointer, which would be like saying that `int` was a pointer to `int`.

Comment: Ooooh, my bad, I misread that at first. Good that I asked then, in case someone else makes the same braindead thought leap I did. That was dumb of me.

Comment: I know that I was thinking that a memory location _generally_ for int and a int* are the same size, since most memory is measured by int for process spaces.

Comment: @jcolebrand Actually, in D, they're often not the same size, because `int` is always defined to be 32 bits, whereas `int*` is `size_t` whose size varies according to the architecture. It is 32 bits on a 32-bit system and so _would_ be the same size as `int` in that case, but on a 64-bit system, it would be 64 bits, so it wouldn't be the same size. But I can see how you might make that leap, given that `int` and `int*` are often the same size in C/C++.

Comment: That was what I was making the point, and most people do compile to a 32 bit space, even if the machine supports more, and I was under the impression (note I don't care _how_ my software runs, so long as it does) that when you compile to 32 bit space, that int and int* are going to be same. I understand what size_t means, and I grok the differences involved, but I'm generally a .NET guy so those things are esoteric for 99.99% of what I do. (I'm a lot more knowledgeable than most devs I talk to, which scares me, but at least I have full appreciation for the .NET stack and the CLR)

Comment: Pointing out this being more about D, tho, is absolutely the point of any discussion here ;-)

Comment: @jcolebrand Windows developers programming in D pretty much have to use 32-bit right now, because dmd does not yet support 64-bit code generation on Windows, but many developers on POSIX systems compile for 64-bit rather than 32-bit. So, assuming that `int.sizeof == size_t.sizeof` is definitely a bad idea. I certainly wouldn't say that `int.sizeof == size_t.sizeof` in the general case, but I could see why a Windows developer would think that way.